# Is there any graphical software package to make urdf file?

Tags: ros, urdf, cad, sw-urdf-exporter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to make urdf file for the robot. the problem is, adding each constraints, geometry dimensions manually in a text file is a bit long process. isnt there any graphical tool(CAD software package) through which i can make my robot urdf?
i have already seen for solidworks add-in, but i want alternate solution.
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213760/is-there-any-graphical-software-package-to-make-urdf-file?/) by [baiju](https://answers.ros.org/users/22012/baiju/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could take a look at [rock-simulation/phobos](https://github.com/rock-simulation/phobos):

[image: image description]

A presentation about this tool will be given at ROSCon15 in Hamburg this year.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baiju](https://answers.ros.org/users/22012/baiju/) on 2015-07-16**:
Thanks for your reply. and i found this addin much powerful. thank you very much.